# Windows Mobile Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I am on a team for a mobile application that is very solid with years of support and development behind it.

Every now and then one or more of our devices will be unable to connect to the WebService.

The device can hit the webservice through a web browser, all of our other devices connect no problem.

The only solution we have is to run the application through Visual Studio in Debug Mode, and then it will work, and continue to work perfectly.

We use a simple HelloWorld webservice call to check connectivity before we being a Synchronization, and this is where we are failing.

This has absolutely baffled me and my colleagues for a while, but it is so rare we haven't worried about it.

Does anybody have any idea what might be causing this issue?

I will be more than happy to provide any more information that you may require.

Comment: Any logs or events recorded on the web service server? If you connect thru USB to device, the PCs network connection is used by the device to connect to the network. Are you using WLAN on device to connect to your network? Then check the WLAN infrastructure (firewalls, routers etc). When you start a Debug session, the device starts some agents to connect between application and Visual Studio. You can even debug remotely on the device using wireless only (no USB needed).

Comment: Is there any rhyme or reason to when they start failing?  A network change?   A move from wired to wireless or anything like that?  Does your web service explicitly disable caching? I'd be inclined to try maybe rebind the adapter and flush any DNS cache to see if that helps.